# Put inside the extended class the parent class

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem with an extended class.

This are the classes:

```
class A{
}

class B extends A{
}
```

Now the problem is that I have a method that returns A , something like this:

```
public A doSomthing(){
}
```

And now I try to do something like this:

```
public static void main(){
   B b = new B();
   b = doSomething();
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to solve this problem?

The only thing I thought about is it to have something like this:

```
class B extends A{
 public B(A a){
  copy all the fields from A to B}
}
```

And then do:

```
A a = new A();
a = doSomthing();
B b = new B(a);
```

Is there a better option?

Comment: Can you elaborate what `doSomething()` is supposed to do? It looks like you are using it as a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally I think you've missed what the assignment operator does. This statement:

```
b = doSomething();
```

changes the value of `b` to whatever the `doSomething()` method returns. It doesn't depend on the existing value of `b` *at all*. So similarly, when you have:

```
A a = new A();
a = doSomthing();
```

... it would make more sense to write:

```
A a = doSomething();
```

Now if you need to create an instance of `B` based on an instance of `A`, then it may well make sense to write:

```
A a = doSomething();
B b = new B(a);
```

or just:

```
B b = new B(doSomething());
```

... but you need to understand when existing values are used and when they're not.

*Usually* I find that when I need to do something like that, it's actually better to use composition than inheritance anyway - that `B` should have a reference to an existing `A` rather than extending `A`. That's certainly something to consider, but without a concrete example we can't say for sure.

Comment: i prefer the way i write, its more convenient and more safe to declare the variable before the assignment. especially if you do the assignment only inside if/try...

Answer (score 0):

You instantiate your object `b` to be of Type `B` instead of `A` therefore `polymorphism` would not work when calling `doSomthing`

Change your object `b` to be of Type `A`

Comment: yes but the i cant do something like:
b.SomeMethodADontHave();

Comment: @user3659858 Look at Jon Skeet's part about using Composition instead on inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have multiple inheritance ([c# example](https://gist.github.com/margusmartsepp/61c3b7b5a380c31f0065)) to enforce method signatures. Instead it would make sense to

```
public static A doSomthing(){
   A result = new A();
   ...
   return result;
}
```

Then you can use:

```
A a = A.DoSomthing();
B b = (B)A.DoSomthing();
```